# Writing Method in C# Which Creates Instance Of Class Using Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, parameters, window

A basic question: I am writing a C# app which has a menu, each menu item is going to open a new window. The windows will all be instances of the Window class.

instead of writing: (EditSettings being the desired name of the target window)

```
Window EditSettings = new Window();
EditSettings.Show();
```

for each one, could I not write a method something like the below, to create the instance?

```
private void OpenSelectedWindow(Window n)
{
    n = new Window();
    n.Show();
}
```

I can't call the method though - I tried:

```
OpenSelectedWindow(EditSettings);
```

Which doesn't work ("The name EditSettings does not exist in the current context'), OR

```
OpenSelectedWindow(Window EditSettings);
```

which doesn't work either

I am so rusty with C# and feel like a twit for asking this, but I can't seem to find examples of this on the internet. Can you create an instance of a class using a method?? What am I missing? Thank you.

**Edit**

The code all happens in the main Namespace:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Attempting to write a method that instances the class
    private void OpenSelectedWindow(Window n)
    {
        n = new Window();
        n.Show();

    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Calling the method
        OpenSelectedWindow(EditSettings);
    }
}
```

I have two .xaml files - EditSettings.xaml (empty) and MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: It's not clear where your method is declared or where the code trying to use it is. Also, why take a parameter if you're going to ignore its value? You can absolutely create an instance of a class within a method, but I suspect that's not *really* what you're interested in. Unfortunately it's hard to see what you're trying to do with your question in its current form.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you needed more code, I will edit and add more.

Comment: Well it's more clarity than anything else. For example, what do you mean *exactly* by "EditSettings being the desired name of the target window"? Are you actually talking about creating instances of different types *derived* from `Window`, and you've got a *class* called `EditSettings`?

Comment: Basically, if I took the OpenSelectedWindow method, and passed EditSettings as the parameter, wherever it has "n" in the method, I would replace that with "EditSettings" (like a string) and, if all worked, it would create a new window called EditSettings.

Comment: An object isn't "called" anything. *Variables* have names, but it's not clear whether that's what you're after either... the variable name within the method is irrelevant elsewhere. If you're interesting in setting the `Name` property of a window, then just set that property via a string.

Comment: Surely when you create an instance of a class, you need to give that instance a name? Am I wrong to say that Window is the parent class, and I'm creating an instance of the class Window, called EditSettings?

Comment: No, you don't need to give an instance a name. An object doesn't have a name, normally... as I said, a *variable* has a name, but two variables can both have values referring to the same object. It's still unclear to me which class you're really trying to instantiate - do you actually have a class called `EditSettings`? If so, you're trying to create an instance of that class, not just `Window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics for this one:

```
private T OpenSelectedWindow<T>() where T : Window, new()
{
    T n = new T();
    n.Show();
    return n;
}
```

Use the method like this:

```
EditSettings editSettingsWindow = OpenSelectedWindow<EditSettings>();
```

Comment: I *suspect* this may be what the OP is after, yes. The question still seems fairly unclear to me, but...

Comment: Agreed, but the question looks so much like an attempt to do exactly that without the OP knowing about generics and/or Reflection.